# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() not working

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to run a jar file from a java program. When I execute following code nothing happens. Name of jar file is Testing.jar. File paths are correct still neither an exception is thrown nor program from Testing.jar runs.

```
package helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing\\dist\\Testing.jar");
    }

}
```

This same jar file runs correctly from CMD. I used following command for that:

```
java -jar "C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing\\dist\\Testing.jar"
```

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` instead or use multiple arg method of `exec()`

Comment: exec start a process, you need to read the input stream, etc, to see what it generates. Or are you sure your program generates visible output (a file being created, a UI appearing)?

Comment: My program generates output using `System.out.println()`. I am running above program from `cmd` so I think it should output whatever it is getting from Testing.jar @JPMoresmau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created process does not have its own console so you need to provide one to see it's running.

```
Process testing= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing\\dist\\Testing.jar");
BufferedInputStream testOutput= new BufferedInputStream(testing.getInputStream());
int read = 0;
byte[] output = new byte[1024];
while ((read = testOutput.read(output)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(output[read]);
}
```

Comment: or run directly in a new command via "cmd /c java..." (on windows)